# React jest test for useEffect on route change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have a tab-based page. Each tab will carry hashtag to switch tabs on click. I added `useEffect` to setValue in the state.

PageManager File:

```
const RolePageManager = () => {
let location = useLocation()
let { uuid } = useParams()

const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
 if (location.hash) {
   switch (location.hash) {
     case '#role_info':
       setTabIndex(0)
       break
     case '#members':
       setTabIndex(1)
       break
     case '#permission':
       setTabIndex(2)
       break
     default:
       setTabIndex(0)
   }
 }
}, [location.hash])
......
```

Test File:

```
 const setState = jest.fn()
 const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState')
 useStateSpy.mockImplementation((init) => [init, setState])
 const history = createMemoryHistory()

 it('something', () => {
   const wrapper = mount(
     <Router history={history}>
       <RolePageManager />
     </Router>
   )
   history.push('view/id/3#members')
   console.log(setState.mock)
 })
```

Issue:

```
  -> state is not updating ::
  { calls: [], instances: [], invocationCallOrder: [], results: [] }
```

If I remove `useEffect` then it works nicely but it will be in the loop. That's why I want to use `useEffect` But failed to set state in the test.

Did I miss anything ? or I should change something ?

Comment: The reason could be that you are spying the useState. That results in a state not actually being updated. If you want the state to be updated, don't spy over it. Let me know if this works, or is there any specific reason you need to spy the `useState`

Comment: Instead of testing component state, you can check whether the tab is selected using it's props or css classnames. Because there is no way to get the value of state in a functional component.

Comment: @AnuradhaKumari , spy helps us to get a change state. If we don't use spy for a functional component we can not trace state

Comment: @soumyasunny, you are right. but is there any way to test the state for a functional component ?

Comment: @SelimReza No, you cannot test the state of a FC using enzyme. It's an implementation detail. Testing implementation detail is against unit testing fundamentals. As I said earlier, try testing `tab.prop("someSelectionProp").value`

Answer (score 0):

Good example.
As far as I understand, you use `enzyme` to mount component.
Enzyme handles state, effects, and other lifecycle related stuff.

The state is a private part of the component. On the other hand, state produces virtual DOM. And resulting virtual DOM could be asserted by jest statements.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be spying on states in react anymore. Tests the effect `tabIndex` has on the rendered content. Maybe you display something different for different values of tab index. Assert on that.

Also, I would recommend turning your useEffect in to a hook called `useTabIndex`, and use that custom hook inside  your `PageManager` module.

Then, while testing PageManager, mock the custom hook. Test the custom hook independently. Try splitting out your useEffects into custom hooks as much as possible. Will keep your code clean and organized, and also much easier to test independently.

I would also recommend using `testing-library/react` for testing hooks. Makes life much easier.